# "GattDeviceServicesResult" can not be found

Tags: visual-studio, dll, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to create client side app using C# for BluetoothLE in **VisualStudio 2015** on **Windows-10** laptop.

I have problem using **Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.GenericAttributeProfile**, the issue is  my code has compile error saying **GattDeviceServicesResult** can not be found.

-> I have added package **UwpDesktop 10.0.14393.3** by Valdimir Postel... (before installing this even "using Wndows.Devices.Bluetooth" was not working)

-> Then I added SDK, windows Kit that was recommended by VisualStudio when I tried to open one of the example (So I accept the recommendation to build that project and VS installed packages of around 9GB)

-> now I can use some of the Bluetooth api's I can scan  and connect to a BLE device, but I can not use classes to deal with services and characteristics because **[GattDeviceServicesResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.bluetooth.genericattributeprofile.gattdeviceservicesresult)** and **[GattCharacteristicsResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.bluetooth.genericattributeprofile.gattcharacteristicsresult)** types are not found. Although these are mentioned on MSDN website

-> searching in forums I came to know I need to add one more reference **System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll**, I browsed to proper folder through add reference utility of VS, I am trying to add this and it does nothing, after I select the dll and click 'Add' just nothing happens. (Add reference is not adding this dll).

Just for example if I select some other dll and try to add, that works fine!

Could somebody please help me with this,

```
using Windows.Devices.Bluetooth;
using Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.GenericAttributeProfile;
using Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.Advertisement;

Int16 uuid_count = 0;
BluetoothLEAdvertisement[] ble_adv = new BluetoothLEAdvertisement[5];
BluetoothLEAdvertisementReceivedEventArgs[] ble_received_adv = new BluetoothLEAdvertisementReceivedEventArgs[5];
BluetoothLEDevice bluetooth_LE_Device;

GattDeviceServicesResult result_service;// This line does not compile 
//Error: CS0246 the type name 'GattDeviceServicesResult ' could not be found
// I am adding reference to "System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime" as mentioned in some solutions 
// the reference does not seems to be added at first when I click add button, but I can see the reference dll being mentioned in solution explorer (assuming it's been added)

// using this to scan available devices
private void scann_ble()
{
    var watcher = new BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher();
    watcher.Received += Watcher_Received;

    watcher.AdvertisementFilter.Advertisement.ServiceUuids.Clear();

    watcher.Start();
    while (true)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
        break;
    }
    watcher.Stop();
}

// receiver event to collect addresses of available devices
private void Watcher_Received(BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher sender, BluetoothLEAdvertisementReceivedEventArgs args)
{
    bool update_adv = true;
    Int16 i = 0;

    if(uuid_count < 5)
    {
        if (uuid_count > 0)
        {
            while (i < uuid_count)
            {
                if (ble_received_adv[i].BluetoothAddress == args.BluetoothAddress)
                    update_adv = false;

                    i++;
            }
        }

        if(update_adv != false)
            ble_received_adv[uuid_count++] = args;
    }
}

// now connecting and checking available services
// as per "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/gatt-client" 
private async void BLE_connect_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int i = 0;
    i = BLE_device_grid_view.CurrentCell.RowIndex;  // getting index from item selected in gridView
    bluetooth_LE_Device = await BluetoothLEDevice.FromBluetoothAddressAsync(ble_received_adv[i].BluetoothAddress);
    // Connection works fine, I can see it on my peripheral device

    //get services - This is not working
    result_service = bluetooth_LE_Device.GetGattServicesAsync();

    if (result_service.Status == await GattCommunicationStatus.Success)
    {
        var services = result_service.Services;
            // ...
    }
}
```

I am using [UwpDesktop](https://www.nuget.org/packages/UwpDesktop) package.

Comment: Can you share a MCVE with us? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Hi, I am first time user on this forum , please don't mind bad structuring of the post for example the line "BluetoothLEDevice.FromBluetoothAddressAsync(ble_received_adv[i].BluetoothAddress); // Connection works fine, I can see it on my peripheral device"  is part of code section but after many tries it just did not fall into code section.

Comment: I have some problem now :( https://i.imgur.com/VUWKLSB.png

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I am also having trouble finding this type

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. My problem was solved after I changed the reference to **windows.winmd** from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata\windows.winmd` to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata\10.0.17763.0\windows.winmd`.

I'm using BLE 4.0 in a WinForm application and I'm working with Visual Studio 2017.

It is very likely that the directory `10.0.17763.0` doesn't exist on every computer, but you may look what versions of windows.winmd exists on your computer.